# Can I prevent credential leakage from csrf or xss attack if I check both cookie and token?

Tags: web-browser, web

Suppose the server can provide one cookie and one token. Then I set them when the user login. The cookie was set to httpOnly and the token will be saved in localStorage. Both of them will be sent back when the user performs submission. AFAIK the cookie can prevent leakage by XSS and the token can prevent CSRF. Can I prevent those two attacks in this way?

Comment: CSRF and XSS have nothing to do with credential leaking. Explain what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

Cookies don't prevent XSS at all. The httponly flag blocks one specific thing that you can do with XSS, but describing that as "prevent XSS" is like saying "I prevent burglaries by bolting my TV to the floor". By the time the TV being bolted - or the cookie being HttpOnly - is relevant, the attacker has already succeeded (broken into your house / a user's session on your webapp), and all you're doing is slightly mitigating the damage.

Just for one particular example, XSS enables you to send malicious requests. The attacker can read the anti-CSRF token out of local storage and include it in their requests, and the browser will automatically include the cookies even though the attacker can't read those, so a successful XSS provides all the benefits of CSRF (and quite a few more), despite any anti-CSRF measures.

In order to prevent XSS, you need to actually block the vectors by which it can happen - user-controlled content being interpreted as code rather than text - through output validation and/or input encoding. As an additional defense you should use a restrictive Content Security Policy, but those are hard to set up securely (although thankfully, with IE being finally end-of-life, all currently-supported browsers now implement support for CSP).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I guess I misdescribed my opinion... Yes, you are right, cookies cannot prevent XSS -- that is not what cookie does. I mean, can it prevent credential leaking with the method the question described?